# Django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and ReactJS Router

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, react-router, axios

I am running into a problem when using react-router and Django (3.0). I am setting up login authentication and I created a superuser just to test out the logging in. Here is what I have done:

**backend/settings.py**

```
...
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
    <ThemeProvider theme = {theme}>
        <Route exact path = {paths.home}>
            <PreLogHome/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path = {paths.login}>
            <PreLogLogin/>
        </Route>
    </ThemeProvider>
</Router>);
```

Then I make the POST call in axios (the qs is used because I already saw: [failed to configure axios with django rest auth to login and get auth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627608/failed-to-configure-axios-with-django-rest-auth-to-login-and-get-auth-token))

```
    axios.post(paths.login, qs.stringify({
        username, password
    }))
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I am trying to redirect to the home page upon successful login. When I type in a random username and password, I just get `"POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2294`, which makes sense because the credentials are not valid. However, if I type in the superuser credentials, I get `"POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2294 \n "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2294`, which means that the server is trying to redirect to '/'. However, on the actual page, I am getting no such redirection. What might the problem be? Is it with react-router? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using  html tags in the React code and setting the name attribute to "username" and "password" as per Django documentation. It seems like axios is not quite Django-friendly...? I could be wrong.